# I want to ask about getElementbyId

Tags: javascript

In my code, I wanted to show the following text: 
"(User) is 153cm tall and weighs 37 kilograms. That qualifies as underweight"

My code is as below. It's not supposed to work but some magic it works except for name.

```
function gogogo() {
    let x=document.getElementById("height").value/100;
    let y=document.getElementById("weight").value;

    let BMI=y/Math.pow(x,2);

    document.getElementById("output").innerText = Math.round(BMI*100)/100;

    let answer;
    if (BMI<18.5)
        answer = "Underweight";
    else if (BMI<=25)
        answer = "Normal";
    else if (BMI<=30)
        answer = "Obese";
    else
        answer = "Overweight";

    document.getElementById("answer").innerText = `"${name} is ${height.value} tall and ${weight.value} kilograms. That qualifies as ${answer}"`;
}
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("height")`
```

Apparently one can simply write:

```
height
```

What's the problem? Can you guys help me to fix it?

Comment: "but some magic it works except for name" - you never seemed to define `name` anywhere in the code you've posted here - where did you actually define it?

Comment: Where you have declared name variable ?

Comment: What's the problem? The fact that `${name}` doesn't do what you want or the fact that you can just use `${height.value}`? If you have an input element with the id "name", you could use `${name.value}`, but your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Total side note, I think you have obese and overweight backwards. I sure hope overweight is less than obese  ;)

Comment: Maybe you need to use input type number for height.

Comment: @h2ooooooo i didnt define it actually. I dont know why it can work either

Comment: You need  to define the name variable in order to use it

Comment: and I think the fact that the elements with ids are already predefined is a legacy feature

Comment: I can't get your script to work on Firefox or IE11. "Let" and the template literals are only available in ES6 or Mozilla JS. What browser are you targeting?

Comment: @MJ im using Chorme.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript traverses the DOM as well insearch of an uninitialized variable. If it finds a `node` with the same `id` as the variable name, it takes the variable as the reference to that `node`.

Example

```
<div>
    <h1 id=title>My title</h1>
    <input type=text value="mi text" id=yourText />
</div>
```

Since the `id`s `['title','yourText']` appear in the DOM tree, you can call them directly ('Though not adviced').

So, calling 
`title.innerText`, would return "`My title`". But calling an uninitialized variable whose id is not in the DOM as well, will give you an `undefined` value

Comment: Thank you for sharing this ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `innerHTML` instead of `innertext`